# EF 4 lazy loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Having problem in displaying relational properties b/w two tables having one(company) to many(package_master) relationship

**Action**

```
public ViewResult Index()
    {

  var companies = db.companies.Include(c => c.aspnet_Users)
                     .Include(c=>c.package_master);
        return View(companies.ToList());
    }
```

**EntitySet**

```
public partial class company
{
    public company()
    {
        this.package_master = new HashSet<package_master>();
    }

    public int company_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string fax { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> sen_sup { get; set; }

    public virtual aspnet_Users aspnet_Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<package_master> package_master { get; set; }
}
```

When I type `Model.aspnet_Users.property1` everything works fine(intellisense) but now I also want to diaplay properties from packege_master(no intellisense)(foreign key table=package_master having client_id as foreign key, public key table=company having company_id as primary key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`package_master` is a collection. You cannot access member properties of package_master entities directly like: `Model.package_master.XXX`. You must iterate the collection to get access to entities.